# How can I put class items in an array Javascript p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a platform style game in p5.js. For the platforms, I made a class, so I can reuse my code and don't repeat myself.

```
class Platform{
    constructor(xCoord, yCoord, width, height){
        this.x = xCoord;
        this.y = yCoord;
        this.w = width;
        this.h = height;
    }
    display(){
        rectMode(CENTER);
        fill("#503707");
        strokeWeight(1);
        rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        fill('#38761d');
        triangle(this.x - 100, this.y - 20, this.x - 80, this.y - 20, this.x - 90, this.y);
        triangle(this.x - 80, this.y - 20, this.x - 60, this.y - 20, this.x - 70, this.y);
        triangle(this.x - 60, this.y - 20, this.x - 40, this.y - 20, this.x - 50, this.y);
        triangle(this.x - 40, this.y - 20, this.x - 20, this.y - 20, this.x - 30, this.y);
        triangle(this.x - 20, this.y - 20, this.x, this.y - 20, this.x - 10, this.y);
        triangle(this.x, this.y - 20, this.x + 20, this.y - 20, this.x + 10, this.y);
        triangle(this.x + 20, this.y - 20, this.x + 40, this.y - 20, this.x + 30, this.y);
        triangle(this.x + 40, this.y - 20, this.x + 60, this.y - 20, this.x + 50, this.y);
        triangle(this.x + 60, this.y - 20, this.x + 80, this.y - 20, this.x + 70, this.y);
        triangle(this.x + 80, this.y - 20, this.x + 100, this.y - 20, this.x + 90, this.y);
    }
    move(){
        this.x-=2;
    }
}
```

New items look like this:

```
let pl1 = new Platform(600,350,200,40);
let pl2 = new Platform(850,250,200,40);
let pl3 = new Platform(1100,200,200,40);
```

I have many more of them. This is how they are drawn in my game:

```
 pl1.display();
 pl1.move();
 pl2.display();
 pl2.move();
 pl3.display();
 pl3.move();
```

With these platforms, I created a collision, so my player can jump on them.

```
if(p1X >= pl1.x-pl1.w/2 && p1X <= pl1.x+pl1.w/2 && p1Y + pHeight >= pl1.y && p1Y + pHeight <= pl1.y + pl1.h && jump == false){
        p1Y = p1Y; 
        velocity = 0;
        jumpCounter = 0;

    }
```

When i'm drawing my platforms, I keep repeating myself with this if statement, since I have more than 20 of these platforms, so I want to make this into a loop (using an array?), but I can't find out how. I once made a for loop with [i], but then the platforms were drawn, but the collision part didn't work anymore.

Can anyone help me out? :)
PS. I'm new to this, still in school.

Comment: where is your collision check living? player, platform, elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Given you existing platform initialization code:

```
let pl1 = new Platform(600, 350, 200, 40);
let pl2 = new Platform(850, 250, 200, 40);
let pl3 = new Platform(1100, 200, 200, 40);
```

You can simply put these into an array:

```
let platforms = [pl1, pl2, pl3];
```

Then to update and draw:

```
for (let pl of platforms) {
  pl.move();
  pl.display();
}
```

And in order to check for collisions with your player:

```
// rather than re-checking this condition inside the loop, just check it once
if (!jump) { // this is essentially the same as jump == false
  for (let plat of platforms) {
    // Note: this if statement only checks if the bottom left corner of the
    // player is colliding with the platform.
    if (p1X >= plat.x - plat.w / 2 &&
        p1X <= plat.x + plat.w / 2 &&
        p1Y + pHeight >= plat.y &&
        p1Y + pHeight <= plat.y + plat.h) {

      // this doesn't make sense, setting p1y to itself?
      // p1Y = p1Y;
      // did you mean:
      // p1y = plat.y - pHeight; // make the player stand atop the platform.
      velocity = 0;
      jumpCounter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want your collision checking to work correctly around the edges of the platform you will want some collision logic like this:

```
// Note I'm inferring from your code that your platforms' x and y coordinates
// indicate the top middle of the platform, but p1X and p1Y indicate the top
// left of your player. This is idiosyncratic, but so be it.
function isPlayerColliding(plat) {
  return (
    // right edge of player is to the right of left edge of platform
    p1X + pWidth >= x - plat.w / 2 &&
    // left edge of player is to the left of right edge of platform
    p1X <= plat.x + plat.w / 2 &&
    // bottom edge of player is below top edge of platform
    p1Y + pHeight >= plat.y &&
    // top edge of player is above bottom edge of platform
    p1Y <= plat.y + plat.h
  );
}
```